# Division 2 lists distinct on 1 column

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select * from ChallengeResults 
where ResultPercentage = 
(
 select CorrectAnswers from ChallengeResults a
 inner join Challenge b on b.ChallengeId = a.ChallengeId
    and a.ChallengeType = '2'
)
/
(
 select NumberOfQuestions 
  from ChallengeConfiguration a 
 inner join Challenge b on a.ChallengeConfigurationId =   b.ChallengeConfigurationId
 inner join ChallengeResults c on c.ChallengeId = b.ChallengeId
 and c.ChallengeType = '2'
);
```

This is my query.

This is the error :

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I want to put the division of these two columns in a single column.
This is used to calculate the percentage of correct answers for a test.

I want it to return a value in the ResultPercentage column.

Comment: Really not clear what you are looking for.   Perhaps a small data sample and desired results.

Comment: When asking for SQL assistance, a [mcve] is a great idea.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message is because your subqueries return multiple values but are used in a way such that the DB is expecting a single value.

It sounds like you want to return a column `ResultPercentage` based on a calculation. The correct place to do this is in the `SELECT` clause of your query, not the `WHERE` clause.

Without table structure and sample data it might not be possible to give you the correct answer, but you likely want something along the lines of:

```
select CorrectAnswers / NumberOfQuestions ResultPercentage, c.*
from ChallengeConfiguration a 
 inner join Challenge b on a.ChallengeConfigurationId =   b.ChallengeConfigurationId
 inner join ChallengeResults c on c.ChallengeId = b.ChallengeId
 and c.ChallengeType = '2'
```

This is your second subquery on its own, but note the `SELECT` portion is altered. It will return a column named `ResultPercentage` that is obtained by dividing `CorrectAnswers` by `NumberOfQuestions` for each row.